# Splitting ReadOnlySequence into lines then ReadOnlySequence by delimiters

Tags: c#, .net-core, buffer

I am trying to split the following chunked memory into `ReadOnlySequence<char>` by newline `\n` and then delimiters (in this example of `"`).

I have the partially working (by lines) code below which when I tweak I get exceptions, and currently have the incorrect output of: `hello`, `fun`, `one`.

I believe my issues are with my use of `ReadOnlySequence.Slice()` and `SequencePosition`, as this seems linked to the position of the starting sequence, and not the start of the sliced `ReadOnlySequence` (at least as I understand).

I am kindly seeking advice towards a corrected example of the below, so that we get the expected:

`hello`, `much`, `fun`, `done`.

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;

namespace NotMuchFunYet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = GetExampleBuffer();

            while (TryReadLine(ref buffer, out var line))
            {
                while (GetString(ref line, out var token))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private static ReadOnlySequence<char> GetExampleBuffer()
        {
            Chunk<char> startChnk;
            var currentChnk = startChnk = new Chunk<char>(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\"hello\".\"mu".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("ch\".".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\"fun\"".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\n\"done\"\n".ToCharArray()));
            return new ReadOnlySequence<char>(startChnk, 0, currentChnk, currentChnk.Memory.Length);
        }

        private static bool TryReadLine(ref ReadOnlySequence<char> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<char> line)
        {            
            var position = buffer.PositionOf('\n'); // Look for a EOL in the buffer.

            if (position == null)
            {
                line = default;
                return false;
            }

            line = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value); // Skip the line + the \n.
            buffer = buffer.Slice(buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value));
            return true;
        }

        public static bool GetString(ref ReadOnlySequence<char> line, out ReadOnlySequence<char> property)
        {
            var start = line.PositionOf('"');
            if (start == null)
            {
                property = default;
                return false;
            }

            property = line.Slice(start.Value.GetInteger() + 1);
            
            var end = property.PositionOf('"');
            if (end == null)
            {
                property = default;
                return false;
            }

            property = property.Slice(0, end.Value);
            line = line.Slice(line.GetPosition(1, end.Value));
            return true;
        }
    }

    class Chunk<T> : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
    {
        public Chunk(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory) => Memory = memory;

        public Chunk<T> Add(ReadOnlyMemory<T> mem)
        {
            var segment = new Chunk<T>(mem) { RunningIndex = RunningIndex + Memory.Length };
            Next = segment;
            return segment;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first property fetch in `GetString()` method resolves this, from:

```
property = line.Slice(start.Value.GetInteger() + 1);
```

To:

```
property = line.Slice(line.GetPosition(1, start.Value));
```

Giving the code:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;

namespace NowMuchFun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = GetExampleBuffer();

            while (TryReadLine(ref buffer, out var line))
            {
                while (GetString(ref line, out var token))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private static ReadOnlySequence<char> GetExampleBuffer()
        {
            Chunk<char> startChnk;
            var currentChnk = startChnk = new Chunk<char>(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\"hello\".\"mu".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("ch\".".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\"fun\"".ToCharArray()));
            currentChnk = currentChnk.Add(new ReadOnlyMemory<char>("\n\"done\"\n".ToCharArray()));
            return new ReadOnlySequence<char>(startChnk, 0, currentChnk, currentChnk.Memory.Length);
        }

        private static bool TryReadLine(ref ReadOnlySequence<char> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<char> line)
        {
            var position = buffer.PositionOf('\n'); // Look for a EOL in the buffer.

            if (position == null)
            {
                line = default;
                return false;
            }

            line = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value); // Skip the line + the \n.
            buffer = buffer.Slice(buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value));
            return true;
        }

        public static bool GetString(ref ReadOnlySequence<char> line, out ReadOnlySequence<char> property)
        {
            var start = line.PositionOf('"');
            if (start == null)
            {
                property = default;
                return false;
            }

            // property = line.Slice(start.Value.GetInteger() + 1);
            // REPLACE WITH BELOW:
            property = line.Slice(line.GetPosition(1, start.Value));

            var end = property.PositionOf('"');
            if (end == null)
            {
                property = default;
                return false;
            }

            property = property.Slice(0, end.Value);
            line = line.Slice(line.GetPosition(1, end.Value));
            return true;
        }
    }


    class Chunk<T> : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
    {
        public Chunk(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory) => Memory = memory;
        public Chunk<T> Add(ReadOnlyMemory<T> mem)
        {
            var segment = new Chunk<T>(mem) { RunningIndex = RunningIndex + Memory.Length };
            Next = segment;
            return segment;
        }
    }
}
```